# PostgreSQL SSH Tunnel to Amazon EC2?

Tags: security, postgresql, ssh, amazon-ec2, tunnel

I've created an Amazon EC2 AMI running CentOS Linux 5.5 and PostgreSQL 8.4.  I'd like to be able to create an SSH tunnel from my machine to the instance so I can connect to the PostgreSQL database from my development machine (JDBC, Tomcat, etc.)  I haven't modified the PostgreSQL configuration at all as of yet.  I can successfully SSH into the instance from a command line, and have run the following command to try and create my tunnel:

```
ssh -N -L2345:<My instance DNS>:5432 -i <keypair> root@<My instance DNS>
```

I don't receive any errors when initially running this command.  However, when I try and use psql to open up a connection on localhost:2345, the connection fails.

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: Please provide more details on "connection fails".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `<My instance DNS>` should be `localhost`.  And you probably don't want to/need to ssh as root.

Comment: <My instance DNS> can't be localhost in both places, otherwise I'm not specifying the Amazon EC2 instance to connect to.

Comment: The *first* one should be localhost.  The second is how you connect to the EC2 instance from your workstation.

Comment: Still not working.  I get the following error message from psql:  psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
 This probably means the server terminated abnormally
 before or while processing the request.

I also see this message in the window where I'm running the SSH command:  channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

Comment: It's working now.  The service had crashed. Once I restarted it everything started working as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: The command in the question seems a bit malformed.. here's what works for me: `ssh -L 2345:localhost:5432 -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem ubuntu@ec2-instance`